# Select SSH identity file when in a session with agent

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

I am "trying" this in server:

```
# ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com
  IdentityFile xxxx
```

What should I put in `xxxx` so when I do in server:

```
git clone git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
```

Git uses a identity in my local, NOT in server, which is located in `~/.ssh/my_another_private_key_file` and not uses the default key `~/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Answer (score 3):

This should go in your ~/.ssh/config file on the machine that you're doing the git clone:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_another_private_key_file
```

If you're doing the clone on the server and the my_another_private_key_file is on local, you might want to add put it in ~/.ssh/identity on server, so when you ssh-add there, it gets added to your ssh-agent process.

Comment: This seems against ssh agent  purpose, since I would copy private key to server, right?